# Want to see the ouput "data.csv" in the desktop or any location

Tags: c#, .net, excel, c#-4.0, export-to-csv

```
        public void CreateFileOutput(object parameter)
        {
            string workSheetName, targetFile;
            workSheetName = "data"; targetFile = "data.csv";
            string strConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + SourceAppFilePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';";
            OleDbConnection conn = null;
            StreamWriter wrtr = null;
            OleDbCommand cmd = null;
            OleDbDataAdapter da = null;
            try
            {
                conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
                conn.Open();
                cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + workSheetName + "$]", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                wrtr = new StreamWriter(targetFile);
                da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
                {
                    string rowString = "";
                    for (int y = 0; y < dt.Columns.Count; y++)
                    {
                        rowString += "\"" + dt.Rows[x][y].ToString() + "\",";
                    }
                    wrtr.WriteLine(rowString);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Done! Your " + SourceAppFilePath + " has been converted into " + targetFile + ".");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                da.Dispose();
                wrtr.Close();
                wrtr.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

XLS file is being converted to csv.I am able to see that in the for loop `wrtr.WriteLine(rowString);`
But I want to see the final output file **"Data.csv"** in the desktop location as I am taking the source .xls file from the desktop. Provide me a solution. Thanks.

Comment: What about `Console.WriteLine(rowString)` or read `data.csv` using `File.ReadAllText(file)`

Comment: Actually I am following the sample given in this link. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yuanwang200409/how-to-convert-xls-file-into-csv-file-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: I don't know where it is saving or code is written for saving as a file. Thanks.

Comment: It's not being saved anywhere but memory right now as you're using a StreamWriter and no associated file.  If it was being saved, it'd be saved in the same directory your application is executing from.

Comment: @John: Did you want to save the file at the desktop or at the location from where the source file was picked up? These two can be different...

Comment: @ Siddharth Rout, Yes, exactly you asked my question. That is what I need, I Want to save from where the source file is taken. Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: @John - I've updated the answer.  Where is your source file at?  Based on the code you posted, it's in the directory you're application is executing (as there's no path), so you don't need to mess with the paths at all.  Just use FileStream to save the file (as opposed to streamwriter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the full path to save the file to the desktop.  You can get the path using the `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory`, like this:

```
string targetFolder =  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
string targetPath = Path.Combine(targetFolder, "Data.csv");
```

Then use FileStream with the full path:

```
fs = new FileStream(targetPath, FileMode.Create);
```

**Edited Per Comments Below**

The key to this is specifying the path to where you want to save the file.  Just giving a file name will put it in the directory the application is excuting from.  An easy way to do this would be to use the `GetDirectoryName` method of the `Path` class.  Assuming the file was passed in, read from a config file, hard coded, etc:

string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(sourceFile);
   string target = path + @"\" + "Data.csv";

If the sourceFile was C:\Data\Input.xml, then path would equal "C:\Data", and target would be C:\Data\Data.csv.

The advantage here is that you can pass a filename with the path, and it will always place the targetfile in the same location.  This lends itself nicely to parameterization of the method, or maybe even having the user select the file through an OpenFileDialog box or similar mechanism.

**Additional Edit Per John's Comment**

Based on the code you posted, the Data.xsl file is in the executing application's folder.  In that case, you'd simply need to do the following:

```
fs = new FileStream("data.csv", FileMode.Create);
```

No need to mess with paths, as the filestream will also go to the executing application's directory.

In the end, it's all about using the information available from the sourcefile (i.e., it's location/path data) and applying it to the target file's full path and name.

Comment: Working fine as expected. Great. Thanks.

Comment: @Tim: I see that you have already initiated in answering John's question. However this is not what he wants. Please see the comments in the question :) Would you like to answer his question or would you like me to post an answer? :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Per the OP's question "But I want to see the final output file "Data.csv" in the **desktop location** as I am taking the **source .xls file from the desktop**."  Not sure how my answer doesn't fit his requirements?

Comment: @Tim: Fair Point. However there is one more interpretation of that sentence. Did you see the comments in the question?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Yes, I read the comments. Per OP's response to your question: "I Want to save from where the source file is taken."  As indicated previously, he is taking the source from the desktop. However, I'll edit my question to handle alternative scenarios.

Comment: @Tim: Ok in that case I will not post an answer :) I'll wait for you to edit the answer and before I upvote as well ;)

Comment: @Tim: The best part is now whether the file is in desktop or any other location, the output will always be in the location where the source file is. This also prevents you from hardcoding the path to the desktop...

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Agreed.  I always cringe when I see anything hard-coded, unless it's done for purposes of quickly testing an idea out.  Believe it or not, I still see a lot of hard-coded stuff when I do code reviews or deal with vendor software.